# Search places by type in Android Google places api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, android-maps-v2

I tried hard to find the way to search places by setting query parameter along with type in`GeoDataClient.getAutocompletePredictions()`api.
But i could not find any way to find exact places with type or name as supplied query.

if i pass 'airport' it gives so many result like places having 'airport' in description or name. 
I just need airports nearby from this api, Guys please help, only option till now is to use web services. But as an android developer i want to use android api.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unluckly geodataapi in android seems to be outdated https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter doesn't have most of the place types https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

Comment: @cgomezmendez , Thanks for replying. So there isnt anyway except web  sevices as of now? What is the best practicee now a days for this problem. I mean is there any popular library for getting nearby places with type and name params ?

Comment: I don't know, asked the question in github just in case https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/issues/65

Comment: This is related to this issue as well: https://issuetracker.google.com/35826944